# jackson serialization is excluding double value 0.0

Tags: java, json, jackson-databind

When trying to map/set double value as 0.0, ObjectMapper is treating it as equivalent to null and thereby excluding when comparing for equality.

I have below test case:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude.Include;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import java.util.Map;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import net.javacrumbs.jsonunit.JsonAssert;
import org.junit.Test;

public class ValidJson {

@Getter
@Setter
static class Temp {
  Double dblValue;
  Integer intVal;
  boolean valid = false;
}

@Test
public void validJson() throws Exception {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
    objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_DEFAULT);

    String json = "{\"dblValue\":0.0}";
    Temp generatedObj = objectMapper.readValue(json, Temp.class);
    Map<?, ?> originalJsonMap = objectMapper.readValue(json, Map.class);

    JsonNode generatedObjMap = objectMapper.valueToTree(generatedObj);
    JsonNode originalObjMap = objectMapper.valueToTree(originalJsonMap);
    Assert.assertSame(originalObjMap, generatedObjMap);
  }
}
```

The above test case is failing with assertion error as `java.lang.AssertionError: JSON documents are different: Different keys found in node "". Expected [dblValue], got []. Missing: "dblValue"`

But when I change the `String json = "{\"dblValue\":0.0}";` as `String json = "{\"dblValue\":1.0}";`, test goes through.

I think there is something going on with default value behavior of Double in conjunction with Jackson, which I am unable to figure it out and solve my above issue. Jackson v2.8.10.

Answer (score 5):

Problem here is with:

```
objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_DEFAULT);
```

Double value 0.0 is considered as a default one and Jackson ignores it. After removing this line everything should work. If you don't want **boolean valid = false** to be included add *@JsonInclude* annotation for **valid** field like this:

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_DEFAULT)
boolean valid = false;
```

Comment: If I include `@JsonInclude` for the attribute, it will be excluded in my REST response(in deserialization process) which I do not want.

Comment: So you want to make that field deserializable only?

Comment: That's correct. I should be able to still deserialize that field.

Comment: @Ramu there's a great article about that here https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-field-serializable-deserializable-or-not